# Why is my sticky element not working when I have position set to sticky?

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon everyone. I'm trying to learn all the CSS positions and I've got all of them down but for some reason I can't get sticky to work and it is just acting like a relative.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!-- Sticky -->
    <section id="sticky">
        <h2>Sticky</h2>
        <div></div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div></div>
    </section>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
#sticky #middle {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong please let me know...... it would really mean a lot.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-fix-issues-with-css-position-sticky-not-working) a nice checklist to go over

Comment: The div you selected is empty, you need to put content in it, or add a width and height to it. Else, if will not show the div.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't have a height property set on the parent. Setting the height property will solve the issue.